# Group permissions not kicking in

Tags: permissions, groups

I have added a user to a group.

```
selah@wwbp-grand:/localdata/harvard$ groups chwinn
chwinn : chwinn perma
```

Then I have recursively changed the group of a directory:

```
sudo chgrp -R perma /localdata/harvard-OCR
selah@wwbp-grand:/localdata/harvard$ sudo chgrp -R perma /localdata/harvard-OCR
selah@wwbp-grand:/localdata/harvard$ ls -la /localdata | grep harvard-OCR
drwxr-x---   4 pwan     perma            4096 Dec 17  2012 harvard-OCR
```

And yet my user still cannot access this directory

```
selah@wwbp-grand:/localdata/harvard$ sudo su chwinn
chwinn@wwbp-grand:/localdata/harvard$ cd /localdata/harvard-OCR
bash: cd: /localdata/harvard-OCR: Permission denied
```

Any idea what is going on and/or how I can fix it?

EDIT:  Tried A.B.s suggestion.  Still getting permission denied.

```
selah@wwbp-grand:~$ ls -la / |grep localdata
drwxrwxr-x 131 root perma  4096 Aug 25 15:19 localdata
selah@wwbp-grand:~$ ls -la /localdata |grep harvard
drwxrwx--x  13 pwan     perma            4096 Nov 16  2013 harvard
drwxr-x---   5 pwan     perma            4096 Feb 27  2013 harvard-csv
drwxr-x---   4 pwan     perma            4096 Dec 17  2012 harvard-OCR
selah@wwbp-grand:~$ sudo su chwinn
[sudo] password for selah: 
chwinnie@wwbp-grand:/home/selah$ ls /localdata/harvard
ls: cannot open directory /localdata/harvard: Permission denied
```

Comment: try `su - chwinn` or try to reboot, fixed similar stuff for me often enough to try it

Comment: @Dodekeract Probably not.

Comment: No luck :(
selah@wwbp-grande:/localdata/harvard$ sudo su - chwinn
[sudo] password for selah: 
chwinn@wwbp-grande:~$ cd /localdata/harvard
-su: cd: /localdata/harvard: Permission denied

Comment: What file system do you have?

Comment: /localdata is an nfs filesystem.

Answer (score 0):

The folder `localdata` has the wrong permissions. To change the permission of a subfolder is not enough. The whole path need the right permissions.

Either you change the group for `/localdata` too via

```
sudo chgrp perma /localdata
```

and to be sure

```
sudo chmod g+x /localdata
```

---

or you set the the search permission for directories `x` for all users

```
sudo chmod o+x /localdata
```

Comment: Just put it in my question.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of an NFS server, the server controls who has access to a file. This means that you need to set the permissions on the server, not locally. So basically you need to ask your server admin to create a `perma` group and add you to it.